# How to remove or disable hoverIntent from this bit of code

Tags: wordpress, hoverintent

Here is some code from a .js file in my wordpress theme. It is what I think is governing a slight delay on my drop down menus upon hover.

```
var cbMainNav = $('.main-nav li');

// Show sub menus
$('.main-nav > li').hoverIntent(function() {

    $(this).find('.cb-big-menu').stop().slideDown('fast');
    $(this).find('.cb-mega-menu').stop().slideDown('fast');
    $(this).find('.cb-links-menu .cb-sub-menu').stop().fadeIn();

}, function() {

   $(this).find('.cb-big-menu').slideUp('fast');
   $(this).find('.cb-mega-menu').slideUp('fast');
   $(this).find('.cb-links-menu .cb-sub-menu').fadeOut();

});

cbMainNav.find('.cb-big-menu .cb-sub-menu li').hoverIntent(function(){

    $(this).find('> .cb-grandchild-menu').stop().slideDown('fast');

}, function() {

   $(this).find('> .cb-grandchild-menu').slideUp('fast');

});

cbMainNav.find('.cb-links-menu .cb-sub-menu li').hoverIntent(function(){

    $(this).children('.cb-grandchild-menu').stop().fadeIn();

}, function() {

   $(this).children('.cb-grandchild-menu').fadeOut();

});
```

It's probably working as it should - its causes a slight delay before the menu shows. Fine for the two large menus but for the little menu (I think that is the one called .cb-links-menu) it is very annoying from a userbility POV as in testing, people are too fast for it and have clicked on the parent menu before the drop down has had a chance to show all the options...

So I have two questions, a simple one and what I imagine is a more advanced one...

1. How do I simply remove the hoverIntent from all this lot so the menus show instantly upon hover?

AND/OR

2. How would I just remove the hoverIntent from the cb-links-menu whilst keeping it on the bigger ones (just incase I decide to use the bigger menus in the future?)

I've looked through the forums and found articles but to be honest I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing when it comes to PHP. I've come a long way though, learning CSS and actually figuring out the problem I have was a thing called hoverIntent and narrowing the problem down to what I think is the bit of code causing it.

If somebody could please help, I would be incredibly thankful

Many thanks,

Richard

Comment: Add 'fast' as your parameter where you call fadeIn/fadeOut methods and see if there is any change. Check your css for slow transitions. Also inspect your javascript file for  variables that may control the script (but it's unlikely based on your structure)

Comment: Hi, so I gave that a try but no luck. The hover menu just fades in fast _after_ the slight delay. I tried adding 0 but the menu appears instantly...instantly after the delay... There are no other delays relating to this drop down menu.